# jquery .ajax function not working properly with Laravel-4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

what I am trying to do is to pass a variable from my view to a controller function..The problem is that I am never routed to my controller's function store.So I cant check if I get the variable as well. The ajax function seems to work(the alert is displayed) but I never get the message success from my controller..

So far my route file is :

```
Route::get('pois', array(
    'uses' => 'MapController@create',
    'as' => 'pois.create'
    ));

Route::post('pois', array(
    'uses' => 'MapController@store',
    'as' => 'pois.get'
    ));
```

My MapController is:

```
public function create()
{

    $bar=new Map;
    $rest=new Map;
    $mag=new Map;

    $bar = Map::where('type', '=', 'bar')->take(10)->get();
    $rest = Map::where('type', '=', 'restaurant')->take(10)->get();
    $mag = Map::where('type', '=', 'magazine')->take(10)->get();

    return View::make('pois.markers')->with('bar',$bar)->with('rest',$rest)->with('mag',$mag);

}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    dd('suceess');

}
```

And my javascript-jquery script is bellow:

```
function ajaxCall(id) {



       $.ajax
        ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "pois",
                data: {"id" : id}, 
                success: function(response)
                  { 
                    alert('ok');
                  }
        });
}



function checkBoxes(elem){

if(document.getElementById(elem).checked==true){

  ajaxCall(elem); 

}
else{

clearMarkers(elem);

}

}
```

Bellow is my HTML as well :

```
@section('main_contents')

    <br/>

    <div class="text-center">





<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="bar" name="group" value="option1" onClick="checkBoxes(this.id)"> Καφετέριες
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="restaurant" name="group"  value="option2" onClick="checkBoxes(this.id)"> Εστιατόρια
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="magazine" name="group"  value="option3" onClick="checkBoxes(this.id)"> Μαγαζιά
</label>



<br/>

</div>

     <div id="map" style="height:500px;"></div>

     @stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not receiving `success` message because you are not returning any message from your controller.

change `dd('success');` to `return 'success';`

```
public function store()
{
    return 'success';

}
```

Your Ajax code:

```
$.ajax
        ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "pois",
                data: {"id" : id}, 
                success: function(response)
                  { 
                    alert(response);
                  }
        });
```

**Edit:**

Change URL `url: "pois"`, to `url: "/pois"`,

**Jquery code:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".checkbox").change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {

            var id = $('.checkbox').val();

            var request = $.ajax({
              url: '/pois',
              type: "POST",
              data: { id : id },
              dataType: "html"
            });

            request.done(function(result) {
                if(result == 'success') {
                    alert("Success");
                } else {
                    alert ("Sorry! unable to add the data");
                }
            });

            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
              console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
@section('main_contents')
    <br/>
    <div class="text-center">

        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bar" class="checkbox" name="group" value="1"> Καφετέριες
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="restaurant" class="checkbox" name="group"  value="2"> Εστιατόρια
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="magazine" class="checkbox" name="group"  value="3"> Μαγαζιά
        </label>

        <br/>

    </div>

     <div id="map" style="height:500px;"></div>

@stop
```

I haven't tested the code but should work.

Comment: No its still not working...The dd function should work...it s shortcut for var_dump and die...the problem is i never reach my store function..

Comment: I think, your Ajax URL has problem. try to change the URL to `/pois`

Comment: I have tried that also...No luck though..Does it mind that my script has some javascript and some other jquery functions..?

Comment: Which browser are you using? if you using Chrome, check the network section from developer tool. you will see the error.

Comment: Would you mind if i change your javascript and HTML. I will use pure JQuery and html5

Answer (score 0):

While making ajax call to controller... you can check like this

```
$jsonResponse = [
                 'imageReceived' =>  $r->hasFile('profilePicture')
                ];
return $jsonResponse;
```

This will return response to console with true or false like this

```
{"imageReceived":false}
```